# Angular6 not finding modules even though they are present in node_modules

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, yarnpkg

I'm working on an Angular6 project and recently I had to change my computer. I restored everything on my new computer from a backup and all seems fine, however since I changed computers, all my Angular projects have stopped working. Now I've synced with other colleagues about the versions of everything we use and I have the latest changes, but only I have this rather peculiar problem.
A bit of context: the project I'm working on uses Angula6 and we use the following tools:

- node 8.12.0
- yarn 1.12.3
- Angular CLI 6.2.9
- Typescript 2.9.2

Now all of these tools have the same versions for all my colleagues where the project is working fine, however with me, it seems that somehow Angular cannot resolve part of its imports. I ran `yarn install --pure-lockfile` and the resulting node_modules folder seems to contain everything I need, however when I run `yarn start` I get errors like this one `ERROR in node_modules/@angular/common/http/src/backend.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.`
I checked the node_modules and it contains 'rxjs' and all of the other modules Angular claims it's not able to find.

What I've done so far is:

- Completely re-install every tool needed to run the project
- Got rid of everything related to npm and reinstalled npm cleanly
- Deleted the project repository completely and pulled cleanly from the remote repo

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Alek

Comment: check the privileges of the npm_module directories - are you sure the yarn install does not run in a different user's session maybe?

Answer (score 0):

After finding out that yarn has a local cache, I deleted that and everything was back to normal.